# What is the easiest way to view the burndown chart in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, scrum, burndowncharts

I am trying to find the burndown chart in Visual Studio and I am at a loss. Is it hiding somewhere in the Team Explorer View? Is it only available via Team Foundation Service on the web? Where oh where is it hiding?

Has anybody ever used it?  Does it work? The only thing I can find doing a web search is that it doesn't work, but I can't even find an image of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The burndown chart is available through Web Access (aaa.visualstudio.com if you're on TFS Service, server:8080/tfs if you're self-hosted). This is where all of the agile planning tools are located.

If you are self hosted a second version of the burndown chart is available through SSRS if it is enabled.

Also, why would it not work? It is a burndown chart.

This is probably the most relevant MSDN on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286619(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Ah.. It's hiding very well.  On ???.visualstudio.com I found that I went to my project, clicked on 'View Task Board' and then hiding in the upper right corner, is a little picture of a chart.  When I click it, WALAH, I get the Burndown chart.  Why did they hide it so well?  Oh well, now I can find it.  Thanks Andrew for making that Clear :-)

Comment: The link should also be available if you open a specific iteration, rather than looking at the overall backlog.